# Print xlsx file using NPOI without using Interop

Tags: c#, .net, npoi

I have generated an xlsx file using NPOI(5.6.0) and I want to print it. I have took a look on the examples on github pages but none of the examples gave the result expected.

my goal is to print xlsx file without converting it to pdf then print it. can you provide me with step by step to print the sheet with landscape orientation with full width and height of the sheet. I can use other library they are applicable , my goal is just to not use Interop.